# Vectors and Norms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, angle

If $a$ and $b$ are vectors such that $\|a\| = 4$, $\|{b}\| = 5$, and $\|{a} + {b}\| = 7$, then find $\|2 {a} - 3 {b}\|$.

I couldn't figure out how to start off this problem. I attempted to use $$\cos \theta = \frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|\cdot \|b\|}$$
But I still don't know what to do. Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Knowing $\|a\|$, $\|b\|$ and $\|a+b\|$ allows you to find $a\cdot a$, $b\cdot b$ and $a\cdot b$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\|a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y}\|^2 = (a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})\cdot(a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})$$

Answer (score 2):

$a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta=49$ and $a^2=16,b^2=25$ thus $ab\cos\theta=4$

$\|2 {a} - 3 {b}\|=\sqrt{4a^2+9b^2-12ab\cos\theta}=\sqrt{64+225-12\times 4}=\sqrt{241}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint** use the square.

$$\|u+v\|^2=<u+v,u+v> $$
$$=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2 <u,v> $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $a.b = \frac{1}{2}(\|a+b\|^2 - \| a\|^2 - \|b\|^b)$

Now Just expand $\|2a-3b\|^2$